# How to rename or delete an alias permanently from system?

Tags: shell, shell-script, alias, printf

I have created one alias in my system,

```
printf "%s\n" "alias shh='sqlplus hfdora/hfdora@hfd2" >> ~/.kshrc
```

Now, I want to change the alias name from `shh2` to `shh`

Also, how to delete other unused aliased from system

I have tried command, `unalias <alias name>`, but it's not getting out from my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant to write from *shh* to *shh2*, right? To change the string, *alias shh*, to the string, *alias shh2*, just edit the Korn Shell RC file and re-source it. You could do this with any text editor, or use the **s**tream line **ed**itor, `sed`.

```
sed -i 's/alias shh/alias shh2/1' ~/.kshrc
unalias shh
source ~/.kshrc
```

Above, `sed` has been asked to substitute (`s/`) the very first occurrence (`/1`) of the string, *alias shh*, with *alias shh2* in the file `~/.kshrc`.

Comment: Thanks ... but if I want to delete the alias permanently then process should be same or anything else?